# cognito login page giving invalid response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

So -

- have amazon ecs app using a load balancer set to authenticate against cognito.
- Using one of amazon's domains (blah.auth...)
- been running fine for ages
- suddenly a few hours ago started giving back

  - err_invalid_response when you tried to login, for that domain/login....
- lots of computers at different sites were doing it
- then manually changed the address to http:// instead of https://
- it gave an error, then redirected to https:// then worked!!!
- and now it just works from everywhere

so...

- does anyone have any idea what's going on...  and more importantly
- anyone have any idea how I troubleshoot this?  Are there any logs anywhere?

Comment: Might have been an issue with the Cognito service itself. Does the Hosted UI web page work fine now?

Comment: The Cognito service does not offer logs anywhere, so I that's a downside of the service.

Comment: yeah but its happened again - and the weird thing is going to the http:// version seems to fix it.  I'm at a loss at how to proceed.   Might have to dump cognito :(

Comment: Report this to AWS Support, I think this issue is better to forward to AWS Engineers.